# haskell-stack does not install QuickCheck

Tags: haskell-stack

Attempting to install [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck), I run `$ stack install QuickCheck`.

```
$ stack install QuickCheck

$
```

The command pauses for a second, then returns to shell printing only a blank line. However, this does **not** appear to successfully install QuickCheck, since the package cannot be found by running `$ ghc-pkg list`.

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep QuickCheck

$
```

And, because I am not able to import `Test.QuickCheck` when compiling a file importing that module.

```
$ ghc ImportsQuickCheck.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling ImportsQuickCheck ( ImportsQuickCheck.hs, ImportsQuickCheck.o )

ImportsQuickCheck.hs:6:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

$
```

I ran the `stack install QuickCheck` from my home folder where it should be installed to my global installation, not from a stack project where it would not.

**Why does `stack install QuickCheck` fail to install that package?**

**Why does it give me no output upon that failure?**

Is there a better way that I can manage my global package set? Perhaps using `ghc-pkg` instead of `stack`? I have previously tried `cabal-install` but would run into problems like this far more than I have using `stack`.

I am using nixos 17.03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you want `stack exec -- ghc-pkg describe QuickCheck`

Longer:

`stack` manages different installations of GHC, and multiple levels of package databases.  So if you run `ghc` or `ghc-pkg` on the commandline, this will likely be a different version of ghc than used by stack.

`ghc-pkg` works by looking at your `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable to get a list of package databases to look at.  If this variable isn't set, then it uses your global and user package DBs.  These are different than the DBs that stack uses (`stack exec` sets the `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` variable)

Also, note that `stack install` is identical to `stack build`.  The only difference is that it will install target executables to `~/.local/bin`.  Quickcheck has no executables, so no need to use "install"